# Unrecognized Rule in lex file

Tags: c, lex

I was wondering why I keep getting an unrecognized run on these two lines

> (\${number})
>
> ({number})

I am unsure as to why this is happening, I believe my aliases are correct, but if someone could double check I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex is not C its uses its own language. A language where whitespace counts and all comments need their own line(s). So: get rid of the line-comments after the definitions.

```
/* Does not work */
letter [A-Za-z]
digit [0-9]
number ({digit})+(\.)?({digit})* // TODO: complete
word {letter}+ // TODO: complete


/* Does work */
letter [A-Za-z]
digit [0-9]
number ({digit})+(\.)?({digit})*
word {letter}+
```